# Kivy: The best way to set username and password for the App

Tags: android, python-2.7, kivy

I want to setup a username and a password to my app
What is the easiest and the best way to do this?
Can you share a python or a kivy code for this?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25147323/saving-login-screen-username-and-password-for-kivy-app
Otherwise combine answer above with [basic Kivy tutorial](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/basic.html)

Comment: First, should the "def login(self):" be under the ScreenApp(App)? or I could define the function anywhere else. Actually, I want to make the user setup a username and password in one of the screens that I made in my code, can I just write the code on the specific screen class?

Comment: Unfortunately I only checked for duplicates and documentation so you can try it for yourself. I can't help you any further with specifics.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving login screen username and password for Kivy app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25147323/saving-login-screen-username-and-password-for-kivy-app)