# How to Make a Password Protected Account for User Kivy

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, kivy

I am trying to make a login page for a user using Kivy. How can I make a bank that logs user logins and times and give them access to the account? Also how do I keep the different settings and files separate from one account to another with Kivy? There is no documentation about having or creating two accounts that the user can login with and a guest.

Sorry. I just need help Kivy (MIT)

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving login screen username and password for Kivy app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25147323/saving-login-screen-username-and-password-for-kivy-app)

Answer (score -1):

Kivy **is not** designed to take care about user management. It's just GUI framework. Like QT or something else. If you want to log in users or store their settings you have to find your way to do it.

1. I advise you to read some about SQL databases.
2. Also if you want to go online with your app read some about [threading module](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TcpCommunication).